# Get custom attribute woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to show a custom product attribute value in my WooCommerce tab; the attribute is named specification. Below is my code which outputs nothing. Ideas?

```
<!-- language: lang-all -->
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    // Adds the new tab 
    $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
        'title'    => __( 'Features', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority' => 50,
        'callback' => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;
}
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
    // The new tab content
    $pa_value = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'pa_specification', true );
    echo $pa_value; 
}
```

Comment: That is because in your callback function you are using `$product->id` in `get_post_meta` and `$product` hasn't been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code in your callback function

```
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
    // The new tab content    
    global $post; 

    $product_id = $post->ID;

    $product = new WC_Product( $product_id );

    $pa_value = $product->get_attribute('pa_specification'); 

    echo $pa_value; 

}
```